# pass user selected range into array then into userform text boxes

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, textbox, user-input

I am trying to have my code prompt the user to select a range of data of 3 width and variable length.  There will only be 30 values those with some rows being blank.  I want to have these 30 values populate into 30 text boxes in a userform of mine (this is so values don't have to be manually entered).  I looked around and figured my route should be `Application.Inputbox` and then pass it into an array were the blank rows can be weeded out with for loops.  I don't know how to pass the user selected table into a 2D array though.

```
Sub selectRange()
Dim r(1 To 14, 1 To 3) As Variant, ran As Range, calB(1 To 30) As Long, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer
dozerCal.Hide
Set r = Application.InputBox("Select the Cal B table.", Type:=8)

For j = 1 To 14
    For i = 1 To 3
        If Abs(r(j, i)) > 0 Then
            calB(l) = r(j, i)
            l = l + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
    lx = calB(1)
    ly = calB(2)
    lz = calB(3)
    rx = calB(4)
    ry = calB(5)
    rz = calB(6)
    ix = calB(7)
    iy = calB(8)
    iz = calB(9)
    sx = calB(10)
    sy = calB(11)
    sz = calB(12)
    p1x = calB(13)
    p1y = calB(14)
    p1z = calB(15)
    p2x = calB(16)
    p2y = calB(17)
    p2z = calB(18)
    lfx = calB(19)
    lfy = calB(20)
    lfz = calB(21)
    lrx = calB(22)
    lry = calB(23)
    lrz = calB(24)
    rfx = calB(25)
    rfy = calB(26)
    rfz = calB(27)
    rrx = calB(28)
    rry = calB(29)
    rrz = calB(30)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    dozercall.Show
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for everyone's help.

Comment: Variable length but 30 is the most values you will have?  That is to say, the maximum will be a 3 column, 10 row table?

Comment: for inputting back into text boxes yes but the table read is usually 3 by 14 with 4 blank rows thus the weeding portion.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:  I missed that you were using the input box wrong, however I will leave this answer as it presents a way to collapse a variable range of user input from a multidimensional array into a single dimension array.**

This should get you started.  Basically it will read the user's input, dynamically create a one-dimensional array of the correct size (rows * columns), and read all the values in the range the user selects to this one dimensional array.  It will then loop through the one dimensional array and print the values back out to the window.

I think this is what you're looking for, but if you need further clarification I can add some.  I added comments so you can see what each section is doing.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TestArrays()

        Dim calBTemp() As Variant, calB() As Variant
        Dim i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
        Dim rngInput As Range

        Set rngInput = Application.InputBox("Select the Cal B table.", "Select Range", Type:=8)

        'Read the user input, check for empty input
        'If empty input, exit the subroutine
        If Not rngInput Is Nothing Then
                calBTemp = rngInput
        Else
                Exit Sub
        End If

        'Create the one-dimensional array dynamically based on user selection
        ReDim calB((UBound(calBTemp, 1) - LBound(calBTemp, 1) + 1) * (UBound(calBTemp, 2) - LBound(calBTemp, 2) + 1))

        'Loop through our multidimensional array
        For i = LBound(calBTemp, 1) To UBound(calBTemp, 1)
                For j = LBound(calBTemp, 2) To UBound(calBTemp, 2)
                        'Assign the value to our one dimensional array
                        calB(x) = calBTemp(i, j)
                        x = x + 1
                Next j
        Next i

        'Loop through our one dimensional array
        For i = LBound(calB) To UBound(calB)
                Debug.Print calB(i)
        Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I figured out my issure, I have posted my answer if you would like to see if there is any issues but for me the code runs beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

So I just wasn't using the `Application.Inputbox` right.  If you return it as a range it will configure to the proper sized 2D array it seams and you can call/manipulate data from there.  Here is a working sub.

```
Sub selectRange()
Dim ran As Range, calB(1 To 30) As Double, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer
dozerCal.Hide
Set ran = Application.InputBox("Select the Cal B table.", Type:=8)
l = 1
For j = 1 To 14
    For i = 1 To 3
        If Abs(ran(j, i)) > 0 Then
            calB(l) = ran(j, i)
            l = l + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
    lx = calB(1)
    ly = calB(2)
    lz = calB(3)
    rx = calB(4)
    ry = calB(5)
    rz = calB(6)
    ix = calB(7)
    iy = calB(8)
    iz = calB(9)
    sx = calB(10)
    sy = calB(11)
    sz = calB(12)
    p1x = calB(13)
    p1y = calB(14)
    p1z = calB(15)
    p2x = calB(16)
    p2y = calB(17)
    p2z = calB(18)
    lfx = calB(19)
    lfy = calB(20)
    lfz = calB(21)
    lrx = calB(22)
    lry = calB(23)
    lrz = calB(24)
    rfx = calB(25)
    rfy = calB(26)
    rfz = calB(27)
    rrx = calB(28)
    rry = calB(29)
    rrz = calB(30)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    dozerCal.Show
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the trick (and forces the user to select 3 columns and 14 rows):

```
Sub selectRange()
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim errorMessage As String
    errorMessage = vbNullString
    Dim ran As Range, calB(1 To 30) As Long, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer

    Do
        'doesn't handle cancel event
        Set selectedRange = Application.InputBox("Select the Cal B table.", _
        Type:=8, Title:="Please select 14 rows and 3 columns" & errorMessage)
        errorMessage = "; previous selection was invalid"
    Loop While selectedRange.Columns.Count <> 3 Or selectedRange.Rows.Count <> 14

    For j = 1 To 14
        For i = 1 To 3
            If Abs(selectedRange.Cells(j, i)) > 0 Then
                calB(l) = selectedRange.Cells(j, i)
                l = l + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
...rest of your code
```